# The firebase function generates a "timeout", error 304

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase to validate that the data sent by the client is authentic using a google or facebook token. But when uploading to functions it generates an error.

**Function execution took 60003 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'**

**Function execution took 232 ms, finished with status code: 304**

On my home pc it runs me normally. Is what I am doing correct or is there some other way to validate the authenticity of the data

firebase.js

```
    var firebase = require("firebase/app");

require("firebase/auth");
require("firebase/firestore");

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: ....,
    authDomain: ....,
    projectId: ....,
    storageBucket: ....,
    messagingSenderId: ....,
    appId: ....
    measurementId: ....
};
let app = null
if (!firebase.apps.length) { 
  app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
}

const auth = firebase.auth();
const google = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
const facebook = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
module.exports = {auth, google, facebook, firebase}
```

datos.js

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./whatsapp-f91a0-firebase-adminsdk-f4fes-a0490d7a8f.json");
if (!admin.apps.length) {
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://whatsapp-f91a0.firebaseio.com"
});
}
const db = admin.firestore();
module.exports = db;
```

Code functions

```
const db = require('./datos');
const {auth, google, facebook, firebase} = require('./firebase')

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const body = []
    req.on('data', (chunk) => {
      body.push(chunk)
    })
    req.on('end', () => {
      try {
        const event = JSON.parse(body)
        let xIdPagina = event.xIdPagina;
        let xTokenUser = event.xTokenUser;
        let xProveedor = event.xProveedor;
        let xMotivoReporte = event.xMotivoReporte;

        // Build Firebase credential with the Google ID token.
        var credential = google.credential(xTokenUser);

        // Sign in with credential from the Google user.
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .then(result =>{
          
          if(xMotivoReporte != "" && xTokenUser != "" && xTokenUser != ""){
            
            if(xMotivoReporte != "eliminar"){
              let grupos = db.collectionGroup('reportes');
              let query = grupos
              .where('xIdPagina','=', xIdPagina)
              .where('xUserId','=', result.user.uid)
              .limit(1)
              .select('xUserId')
              .get()
              .then(querySnapshot  => {
                const documents = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
                if(documents.length < 1 ){
                  let grupo = {
                    xIdPagina: xIdPagina,
                    xUserId: result.user.uid,
                    xProveedor: xProveedor,
                    xEmail: result.user.email,
                    xMotivoReporte : xMotivoReporte
                  }
                  let addDoc = db.collection('facebook_spa').doc(xIdPagina).collection('reportes').add(
                    grupo).then(ref => {
                    res.statusCode = 200
                  });
                }
                else{
                  console.log('Errores de aqui');
                  res.statusCode = 400
                }
              })
              .catch(err => {
                  console.log('Error getting documents', err);
                  res.statusCode = 404
              });
            }else{
              let grupos = db.collection('facebook_spa');
              let query = grupos.where('xEstado', '==', true)
              .where('xId','=', xIdPagina)
              .where('xUserId','=', result.user.uid)
              .limit(1)
              .select('xUserId')
              .get()
              .then(querySnapshot  => {
                const documents = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
                if(documents.length != 0){
                  const res = db.collection('facebook_spa').doc(xIdPagina).delete();
                }
                else{
                  res.statusCode = 404
                }
              })
              .catch(err => {
                  console.log('Error getting documents', err);
                  res.statusCode = 404
              });
            }
          }
          else{
            throw Error('reporte');
          }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          // Handle Errors here.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          // The email of the user's account used.
          var email = error.email;
          // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
          var credential = error.credential;
          // ...
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("El error esta aqui: " + error)
        res.statusCode = 400
      }
      finally {
        res.end()
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: That means your function didn't send a response within the default timeout of 60s.

Comment: @DougStevenson Hi. Yes I know it is time out but I don't know why that happens. Since on my pc it works fine. Greetings

Comment: Add some more debug logging to see how your code is actually being executed.  Make sure it gets to the path you expect where it sends the response.